# Implement Exoplayer Analytics and PlaybackStats

Tags: android, google-analytics, addeventlistener, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am new to android development and am trying to create an app using googles' exoplayer. I have the player working but am trying to create a function that returns the players' playback stats. Currently, when this function is called the app crashes. Can anyone help me understand why my code isn't working or point me to example code of a project using exoplayer's *playbackStatsListener* and *analyticsListener*?

Create playback listener

```
private final PlaybackStatsListener 
playbackStatsListener = new PlaybackStatsListener( false, (eventTime, playbackStats));
```

Add analytics listener

```
Private void preparePlayer(){
   ... 
   samplePlayer.addAnalyticsListener(playbackStatsListener);
   ...
}
```

Function to get stats

```
Public JSONObject getStats(){
   JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

   PlaybackParameters param = this.samplePlayer.getPlaybackParameters();

   data.put("pauseCnt", this.playbackstats.totalPauseCount);
   data.put("speed", param.speed);

   return(data);
}
```

One thing that confuses me is when and how I should declare playbackstats. Also, do I need to be in an event call to access playbackstats?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can add the crash logs that will help people get you the right answer.